# Couchbase cli cluster-init returns "too many values to unpack"

Tags: couchbase

I'm trying to execute cluster-init command via couchbase cli on node which on which I've already installed and started couchbase.
This is the command that I'm using:

```
/opt/couchbase/bin/couchbase-cli cluster-init --cluster=127.0.0.1 --cluster-username=admin --cluster-password=password --cluster-port=8080 --cluster-ramsize=1024 --cluster-index-ramsize=200
```

Output that I get is:

```
ERROR: command: cluster-init: 127.0.0.1:8091, too many values to unpack
```

Any ideas on what might be the issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in the couchbase-cli code that unfortunately was not caught before the release. It has been fixed and will be available in the Couchbase 4.1 release. The patch that fixes the issue is below.

https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-cli/commit/3505a587c89665f6b410b99e963d7b414414d7e6

Also, the error message is bad, but you shouldn't be losing any functionality. Since your using the community version or couchbase you are required to have either all of the services enable or just the data service. If you don't you will be up seeing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following to your commandline:

```
--service='data;index;query'
```

(or maybe without the single quotes).
based on [this](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/cluster-init-error-too-many-values-to-unpack/5377) link